# Can't find emulator in VS Code. How can fix

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

```
flutter emulators
```

"Unable to find any emulator sources. Please ensure you have some
Android AVD images available." I am using win10, but when I want to connect to emulator with flutter I get this error. How do I introduce my device in genymotion to Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: Did you tried debugging in a real device to check if everything is installed well ?

Comment: As far as I know, I tried many ways, even I just debugged on chrome and I didn't come across an error. "Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:60076/HA-gOVT0bec%3D/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60076/HA-gOVT0bec=/ws
 Running with sound null safety
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:60076/HA-gOVT0bec=/ws
"

Comment: in chrome every thing will work without hustle, but in android you need SDK SDK tools and JDK and Java installed in your machine.

Comment: Normally I did not get such an error, but I reset my computer 2 days ago and encountered such an error. I installed genymotion and created a virtual machine, git file installed, java defined. Environment variables are fine. Unfortunately, it hasn't detected genymotion for 2 days vs code.

Comment: have you tried enabling debugger mode in it ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I'm getting this result : "No problems have been detected in the workspace"

Answer (score 0):

Launch your emulator, then run in terminal

`flutter devices`

Then in your file **launch.json** inside **.vscode** folder in your project, you can create something like the code above and name the emulators and put the deviceId that you see when you write ´flutter devices`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "budgets",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "007153FC-9053-4A68-851A-20D1B6013518"
        },
        {
            "name": "iPhone 11",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "73EE2120-4DB0-42FD-AA3A-DD4D417FE40A"
        },
        {
            "name": "Android",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "emulator-5554"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't find the deviced ID even though I looked at genymotion and vs code. Where can I get it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling vs code, genymotion and virtualbox and reinstalling them.